# Create Home button menu (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I want to create home layout with 6 button for menu

How can create this list with girdview or relative layout ?

my problem is when rotate screen relative layout don't work good and design not good

Comment: grid view is better in your case. try it.

Comment: You can use this link for your design [android developer](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) and for that issue gridview is better than I think

Answer (score 2):

For a stylish looking of your Home page. its always recommended to use two layouts as

layout-land and layout. so that it will be better to look. Whether it may be Relative layout or Linear Layout or gridview use two layouts. Its not necessary but for the purpose of looking its recommended

Comment: Do I need layout-land for other screen size ?

Comment: now, I have 4 layout for difference size, and now with your solution is going to be 8 layout, any other solution???

Comment: @OmidMafakher, I am not forcing you to create all layouts in landscape. i am just suggesting you to create landscape layout which doesn't look better in portrait mode. understand the point